# VBA excel setting print area

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting a print area using named range, since it's a table and it grows.
When I execute, the headings wont print. How can I adjust this to print the named range(Table3) along with the headers?

I tried;
`ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range("Table3{Headers}").Address`
but only printed the Headers.

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range("Table3").Address
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
```

I want the headers and Table3 to print.

Comment: Correct. I get Table3 but no headers

Comment: I know when  named the range as Table3, I checked the box that says my table has headers. Not sure how that might play out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table is a [`ListObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject). Use the [`ListObject.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.range) property to return the `Range` that the table refers to (includes headers).

```
Dim myTbl as ListObject
Set myTbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mysheetname").ListObjects("Table3")
...
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mysheetname").PageSetup.PrintArea = myTbl.Range.Address
```

Change the sheet name as needed.